# php curl post HTTP 401 Unauthorized

Tags: php, curl, post

I am trying to post a form where the destionation url is not my server.

I get this message in the response header of the curl post

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: kjses=19d6fb64-be95-49d9-9145-005d0fbdbd60^KaV8Q0ZjHd0ow0/cbEg60A==; Path=/; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 25 Aug 2016 00:15:52 GMT
Server: None
```

If I create a html page on my local server to simulate the form, when I submit the form, its working. That let me think the error is from my curl setting since they (the other website) don't block post that come from another origin

Here my curl

```
$param = array(
                        "token" => "1472083067316"
                        ,"from" => "mail@hotmail.com"
                        ,"fromName" => "Bob"
                        ,"message" => "unbeaugrosmessage"
                        ,"bbToken" => "gfdg4t3gfg"
                        ,"bbUserInput" => "3183"
                        ,"_sendCopyToSender" => "on"
                        ,"adId" => "1193173128");

        $postvars = '';

        foreach($param as $key=>$value)
        {
            $postvars .= $key . "=" . $value . "&";
        }

        $curl = curl_init();


        $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
        $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
        $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
        $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
        $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
        $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
        $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
        $header[] = "Pragma: ";

        $tmpfname = '/home/seb/ui/app/storage/logs/laravel.log';
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1468.0 Safari/537.36");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $tmpfname);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $tmpfname);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);                //0 for a get request
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postvars);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

        $result=curl_exec($curl);
        $header_size = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
        $header = substr($result, 0, $header_size);
        $body = substr($result, $header_size);
        Log::error($header);
        Log::error($body);
        Log::error(curl_exec($curl));
        curl_close($curl);
        Log::error($result);
```

result is empty

Comment: Cross site posting permission is controlled by the server.